# custom classpath / modifying classpath in a junit5 test

Tags: junit5

Is it possible do modify/filter the classpath of a test?
Reason: Our SWT GUI tests are including all platform SWT libs and we need to exclude the wrong libs. In junit4 it was possible with a custom Runner (@RunWith).

With junit5 is it possible to inject/modify a custom classpath with @ExtendWith or at phase @BeforeAll ?

Comment: Where do you need to exclude them from?

Comment: It would be great to create an extension which can adapt the classpath of the actual test at classlevel. like @ExtendWith(SWTFiltertClassLoader.class)

Comment: Or to extend the current classpath of the test to include additional directories. like @ExtendWith(AddCustomFoldersToClasspath.class)